# android No successful match so far

Tags: android, spannable

I'm trying to change the background color of a specific text e.g. this is the text `xxxx 0 visible` and I want to change background color of `0`.

**Here is my code**

```
private TextView setTVBenutzername(View view, Question question, int groupPosition) {
        String BenutzerName = question.Benutzername;
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtBenutzername);
        textView.setTag(groupPosition);
        textView.setOnClickListener(this.onGroupClickListenerAll);
        textView.setOnLongClickListener(this.onGroupClickListener);
        Integer Bewertungen;
        Bewertungen = question.Bewertungen;
        if (Bewertungen != null) BenutzerName += " " + Bewertungen + "";
        BenutzerName += " " + question.onlineState.getStateString();
        textView.setText(BenutzerName);

        final Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(textView.getText().toString());
        // Setting Foreground color to the entire text to red
        spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
                0, textView.getText().toString().length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        // Getting the indices of the number (Bewertungen)
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(textView.getText().toString());
        matcher.find();
        int startIndex = matcher.start();
        int endIndex = matcher.end();

        if (question.online && question.onlineState.state > MainActivity.OnlineState.invisible.state) {

            // Setting Foreground color
            spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorUserOnline)),
                    startIndex, endIndex,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            textView.setText(spannable);
            textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_online, 0);

        } else {

            // Setting Foreground color
            spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorUser)),
                    startIndex, endIndex,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            textView.setText(spannable);
            textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        return textView;
    }
```

App crash when I run.

**Error is**

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.ensureMatch(Matcher.java:1116)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.start(Matcher.java:1158)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.start(Matcher.java:1130)
    at de.com.limto.limto1.Controls.QuestionsAdapter.setTVBenutzername(QuestionsAdapter.java:1645)
    at de.com.limto.limto1.Controls.QuestionsAdapter.setGroupView(QuestionsAdapter.java:1203)
    at de.com.limto.limto1.Controls.QuestionsAdapter.getGroupView(QuestionsAdapter.java:1156)
    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:446)
```

Answer (score 0):

`find()` method returns a `Boolean` indicating whether a `match` has found or not, and without `match` you cannot get the `index`, so wrap inside `if` condition, like below

```
if(matcher.find()){
        int startIndex = matcher.start();
        int endIndex = matcher.end();

        if (question.online && question.onlineState.state > MainActivity.OnlineState.invisible.state) {

            // Setting Foreground color
            spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorUserOnline)),
                    startIndex, endIndex,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            textView.setText(spannable);
            textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_online, 0);

        } else {

            // Setting Foreground color
            spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorUser)),
                    startIndex, endIndex,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            textView.setText(spannable);
            textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
}
```

Comment: Up to this code, the app is working fine. When the user is online, the color of `0` out of `Abc 0 visible` change and the color of `Abc visible` remains red. But when I change the status from visible to offline then `Abc visible` text remains in red color but it should be changed to green color.
Here in the code the coloruser is green color. This is one problem and the other problem is that if `Abc` is replaced by `Ab` user online, then its name will be shortened and the color of another word will change. how can I solve this?